# all validators executed when page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can i run all validators when page is loaded. I need to show * in all input text fields that are necessary. I have require field validators for that fields, can i run it by default when page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [Page.Validate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx) during your `Load` phase should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For WinForms you have [ValidateChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159409.aspx), would it work for webforms?